# In VSTS, How to constraint/restrict a team member's working capacity in case working in multiple projects

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Assume a team member A works with multiple projects/applications(P1,P2,P3). While doing Capacity planning, i'm able to allocate him with 8hrs per day in each project(P1,P2,P3). Is there any availability to freeze/constraint a team member's capacity to 8hrs in all projects combined(capacity should be restricted to 8hrs in combined). Any provision to create such a rule/restriction on account level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn’t the feature to constraint a team member’s capacity to 8hrs in all projects. You need to do it manually.

There is a similar user voice that you can vote and follow, you also can create a new user voice for this feature.

[Ability for TFS sprint capacity and days off for a project to be inherited by teams](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/10885188-ability-for-tfs-sprint-capacity-and-days-off-for-a?page=1&per_page=20)

Comment: Thanks for providing an appropriate forum to make a voice. Appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: You can't do this by technical means. The capacity per day field is not validated in any way. You can even enter more than 24h as capacity.

The capacity planning has to be done by organizational means.
I our projects it has proven as good practice to not even plan full 8h per day per person. For capacity planning we only assume 6h per developer. The rest is used for meetings, support and other unplanned stuff.

Comment: I too found the same which in turn is my issue. Our project has multiple applications and some members are engaged in more than 1 application/project. So, its become tedious for us to track manually. I'm checking if some or other way, is it possible to restrict a team members capacity to 8hrs per day.